# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении с вопросительным знаком?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и, ссп, вопросительный-знак

Что такое медитация(,) и для чего она нужна?

Comment: скорее всего да, ведь это два разных вопроса не связанных друг с другом: что такое? для чего? Так что обычное сложносочиненное.

Comment: @Буратино Это у вас уже грамматика)   Но связаны ли сообщения по семантике? Как вы считаете?

Comment: @Sharon Вопросы разные, так что и семантика разная. Можно без запятой написать, но это исключение скорее. Тогда будет подразумеваться некое внешнее обобщение. Скажите: что такое медитация и для чего она нужна?

Comment: @Буратино  Да, интересно, обобщение действительно нужно. А без БСП можно обобщить, по контексту например?

Comment: @Sharon не могу точно сказать пока вы не приведете пример, но скорее всего в русском всё может подразумеваться, на то и авторская пунктуация.

Comment: А пример вы должны придумать))  Надо противопоставить формы ЧТО и ДЛЯ ЧЕГО.

Comment: @Sharon Ну вот смотрите, ещё такой момент: у Александра приведены примеры, но, они не соответствуют запросу. "Это кто такие и что им надобно?" - на это кто такие можно ответить однозначно, то есть тут семантики особо нет. Это кто такие - это Семёновы. Когда конференция - конференция начнётся в 10:00. А тут идет две разные именно семантики, что такое медитация - тут однозначно не ответить, тут придется дать расшифровку через понятия и тп. А второй вопрос уже о конкретике, как это на практике реализуется. То есть к вопросам Александра у меня нет вопросов, там не нужна запятая, а тут - нужна.

Comment: Возможно, интонации разные) хотя и вопросительные. Вопросительные интонации могут быть разные)? То есть в вопросы Александра первая часть несемантическая, а по сути уже содержит ответ в вопросе. Когда вы ко мне придёте - утверждение, вы ко мне придёте - да, когда - в пять. А тут простыми ответами не отделаешься.

Comment: Хотя может вот этот вопрос: Который теперь час, и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда? Сначала речь о времени, а потом про поезд. Тут нужна запятая. А вот тут не нужна: Это кто такие и что им надобно? - вопрос про них и про их дела, дела принадлежащие им.

Comment: Спасибо, надо еще подумать.  Разных интонаций нет, но мы не обязаны объединять вопросы. Пусть у каждого будет отдельная вопросительная интонация (для этого логическим ударением выделяем первую часть).  Да, у вас интересные примеры, но их тоже можно объединить.  Нужно бы такие, чтобы было нельзя это сделать.  Например: Откуда мне знать, и почему ты вообще меня об этом спрашиваешь?

Comment: @Sharon а если так: Откуда мне знать(,) и почему вообще об этом спрашиваешь? - хотя тоже, спрашиваешь уже выдает личное обращение к ТЫ, подразумевает ТЫ. Это кстати фишка русского, подлежащее не обязательно, окончания достаточно. Тогда так: Откуда мне знать(,) и почему вообще нужно это спрашивать?

Comment: Здесь нужны только односоставные предложения (ты). Но всегда ли их можно объединить интонацией?  Предложения могут иметь разную тематику, а также  бывают распространенные предложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если обе части предложения произносятся с вопросительной интонацией, запятая не нужна.

*Что такое медитация **и** для чего она нужна?*

[**Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133)

> **3.** Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
> **1)** вопросительные предложения: *Это кто такие **и** что им надобно?* (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; *Который теперь час **и** сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?; Когда состоится конференция **и** какова повестка дня?; Вы придёте ко мне **или** мне прийти к вам?*

Answer (score 0):

Я бы ставил запятые в таких предложениях по следующему принципу:

Если речь идет об одном и том же, то запятая не нужна. А если речь идет о разном, то ввиду отсутствия обобщения, запятая нужна.

Что такое? - это один вопрос, про медитацию.

И для чего? - это вопрос другой, уже про что-то, что не медитация.

*Что такое медитация, **и для чего** она нужна?*

И, кстати говоря, в приведенном Александром правиле есть примечание к 1 пункту:

> Примечание. Перед союзом и запятая ставится также в тех случаях, когда он присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части сложносочиненного предложения или повторяющим его...

Она - личное местоимение и подлежащее, относящееся к первой части.

И для чего - дополнительный вопрос, не связанный с первым, И использовано для создания присоеденения дополнительного вопроса:

Но запятая была бы не нужна, если бы было:

Что такое медитация и что для неё нужно?

Comment: Примечание даётся в 1-м пункте, где рассматриваются "обычные" сложносочинённые, без каких-либо общих частей и членов.

Comment: То есть если вопросы, по правилу ставить запятую не нужно никогда?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец а вот в таком: Откуда мне знать(,) и почему ты вообще меня об этом спрашиваешь?

Comment: Нет, не думаю, что никогда. В длинных предложениях не особо соединишь вопросительной интонацией, а здесь всё короткое. Поэтому я и написал, что если произносится, то есть если кто-то у кого-то спрашивает. А вообще, предложение из вопроса похоже на заголовок популярной статьи, где не нужен знак вопроса, тогда и запятую поставим.

Comment: Может быть это вообще примыкание, а не сложносочиненное? Сначала скажи мне, что такое медитация, а затем, рассказывай для чего она нужна - разнесение фраз. Если заголовок, то не нужно, да. Потому что заголовок - уже что-то объединяющее.

Comment: В вашем примере я бы поставил запятую. Ну не описаны все случаи, не рассмотрены все интонационные модели и отношения частей... Что ж поделать?..

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец это так, вот меня и смущает, что прямо попадает под описание присоединения, если бы не вопрос...

Comment: Лучше написать так; "Откуда мне знать? И почему ты вообще меня об этом спрашиваешь?! Иди, в общем... "   Другими словами так.   НЕ НАДО СОЕДИНЯТЬ, ЕСЛИ ХОЧЕШЬ РАЗДЕЛИТЬ.  Но вообще интересно найти решение подобных задач у классиков.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна:

***Что такое медитация и для чего она нужна?***

В вопросительном предложении между двумя частями, соединенными союзом И, запятая **не ставится**.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а в приведенном ниже предложении тоже не нужна запятая?  Что такое медитация (никак не могу понять) и для чего она на вообще-то нужна?

Comment: Да вроде нет. А может ставиться?